# Category Theory: Function Equality by Composition Clarification

Tags: category-theory, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I am new to category theory, so apologies if this is obvious.

I recently learned about function equality via composition:

`∀c∈C·∀g,h : c→a` If `f∘g = f∘h ⇒ g=h` Where `C →g→ A →f→ B` & `C →h→ A →f→ B`

This kind of makes sense, but only for the specific function `f`. From what I can tell, functions `g & h` could be considered identical in certain situations, for instance:

- `g = sin(x)`
- `h = i*sin(x)`
- `f = abs(x)`

Clearly other functions of `f` could distinguish between the two functions. I'm sure I've misunderstood something but am unsure as to where.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you've written. What is the quantifier on $f$?

Comment: I don't think this function equality make any sense.. (easier example is to take $g,h$ be whatever and $f$ be constant). I think this is only true if $f$ is 1:1 however I don't understand what this has to do with category theory.

Comment: where did you learn about this?

Comment: The implication $\forall C\in\mathcal{C},\forall g,h:C\rightarrow A, f\circ g=f\circ h\Rightarrow g=h$ is the definition of $f$ being a monomorphism. In the category of sets, this is equivalent to $f$ being injective. Not every morphism satisfies it, this is certainly false for the absolute value function.

Comment: @Roland Ahh, I see. I misunderstood what `g=h` was actually telling me. Its not that `g` is actually equal to `h` (as I had suspected), but that f is a monomorphism. If you write as an answer I'll select it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: We do have for given $f, g: A\to B$, $f=g$ if and only if $\forall C\in\mathsf{Ob}(\mathcal{C}).\forall h : B \to C. h\circ f = h\circ g$ (and similarly for precomposition). This might be what you are thinking of.